# Fill-in which is of date type can it will remain be blank?

Tags: openedge, progress-4gl

I have a fill-in which is of date format. Firstly it contains date and after that I want to update this date with null, but this is not updating.
Plz tell

Comment: It's easier to help if you try to insert some code. Even not working code!

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
 <Yourfillinhere>: screen-value in frame {&frame-name} = ?.
```